# How to show loading panel in WPF application while loading data in gridcontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

How can i use loading panel in WPF using C# while loading data into gridcontrol by clicking button? I am using devexpress "gridcontrol".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to use the loading panel? Are you processing large volumes of Data? If so, use the approaches described in [Processing Large Volumes of Data](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11144) help-article. These approaches can avoid any UI-blocking operations.

Anyway you can use the [GridControl.ShowLoadingPanel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_ShowLoadingPaneltopic) property.

Comment: Thank You so much for your valuable assistance.